# how to show the latest changes in my console.log in node.js

Tags: node.js

This question might be very primitive but I just started learning node stuff so please bear with me. I have many `console.log` in my code and when I use React I just refresh the page to see the latest changes in the logs. But now that i am learning node, refreshing the browser doesn't do that and I have to close and re-run `node index.js` in my command line. So what is the way of seeing my console.log lates changes? By the way, I'm using VSC as editor.

Comment: If you are editing the server file index.js and you want your server to run the latest server code, then you have to stop and restart your server.  There is no other method.  Client-side javascript files are unloaded and then loaded again when you do refresh, but your server runs continuously so the only way to refresh its files is to stop the server and restart it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. you should restart your node server (index.js). You can use [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) to do this for you automatically when you save a file. So instead of node index.js, you can just run `nodemon index`

Comment: o ok then, so i wasn't very off the road and doing silly things LOL